# T-SQL Table Variable Creating PHYSICAL Table!

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

OMG! What am I doing wrong?

```
declare @WTF TABLE (
 OrderItemId int
)

SELECT TOP 20 OrderItemId as OrderItemId INTO [@WTF] FROM ac_OrderItems

SELECT * FROM [@WTF]
```

**Problem A**: This creates a PHYSICAL table called @WTF. WHY?? I thought this was in memory only?!

**Problem B**: The last line of code, if I do select * from @WTF... WITHOUT the [ ], it returns NOTHING. What is the significance of the [ ]?

I need serious help. I'm losing my MIND!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about removing the `[ ]` from the `SELECT ... INTO` ?

Comment: I had NO idea that SELECT INTO creates a PHYSICAL table! Thanks so much for everyones knowledge. You saved me from EATING A BULLET.

Comment: As an aside, don't assume that a table variable will ALWAYS be memory only.  This article is rather outdated but is still mostly relevant and accurate: http://databases.aspfaq.com/database/should-i-use-a-temp-table-or-a-table-variable.html

Comment: The significance of the [] is that it makes it a literal.  It will make a table called "@WTF" whereas you want to insert it into the variable table @WTF.  The difference being that the SQL compiler thinks you really want the @ in the table name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[What you experience is by design](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188029.aspx):

> SELECT…INTO creates a new table in the default filegroup and inserts the resulting rows from the query into it.

The alternatives are to either:

1. Not define the `WTF` table, and rely on the behavior to create it automatically
2. Use the existing code, but change the `SELECT INTO` into an INSERT:

   ```
   INSERT INTO @WTF
     (orderitemid)
   SELECT TOP 20 
          oi.orderitemid
     FROM ac_ORDERITEMS oi
   ```

Mind that when using `TOP`, you should be defining an `ORDER BY` clause to ensure data is returned consistently.

Comment: On point 1, of course you can't SELECT INTO a table variable; it must be declared first.

Answer (score 4):

Because Select INTO always creates a **physical** table. What you want to do is an Insert Into.

The Select INTO is creating a physical table named '@WTF', just as it's supposed to do.

Comment: Ah, yeah, you got it. Removed my answer.

Comment: How would you re-write the select into query into a insert into?

Answer (score 2):

The secondary answer is that the reason it seemed to only work with brackets [] is because of the @ sign.

```
select * from  @WTF
```

is selecting off of your empty table variable, where as

```
select * from  [@WTF]
```

is selecting off of the new physical table the select into created that was populated with data. The brackets are used to allow characters not normally allowed in a table or column name so their use here signifies you are looking for a table with the name @WTF instead of a variable named WTF.

Answer (score 0):

All table variables are "physical" tables.

Your belief that they are "memory only" is a myth. They reside in `tempdb` and are shown in the metadata views with system generated names such as `#4BAC3F29`. The structure of a table variable is identical to a `#temp` table.

You cannot use `SELECT ... INTO` with table variables but can do with `#temp` tables. Your code just creates a new user table called `@WTF` in your user database as indicated in the other answers.